Why am I unable to receive image file uploads on my Express server from my client?
On the client side I am just using react-drag-drop-files component
Client:
import { FileUploader } from "react-drag-drop-files";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const fileTypes = ["JPG", "PNG"];


export default function DragDrop() {

    const handleChange = (file) => {
        console.log(file)
        fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/upload", {
            method: "POST",
            body: file,
            headers: {
            "Content-Type": "image",
            },
        })
    };

    return (
        <FileUploader handleChange={handleChange} name="file" types={fileTypes} />
    );
}

And on the server side I am receiving it like so:
app.post("/api/upload", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("Image", req.body, req.files)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});

I clearly see the img file being console.logged on the client side, but on the server side the console.log is empty or undefined. Why?

content-type image is invalid. What format do you intend to send? A binary or frammed in a multipart form?

How is your express app handling uploads, eg any specific middleware?

@Evert Why is content-type/image invalid? I also tried image/jpeg as well

@DaveNewton no middleware

@JobHunter69 image/jpeg is a correct content type. If this is express, you can then read the body with (for example) req.pipe(). You'll get a stream to the file (this is what you want),  you gotta decide what to do with this stream.

@Evert Why would I use req.pipe() and not just req.body? or req.files? I don't understand how this works

Generally you need middlewares to put things in those objects. For instance, bodyparser ensures that JSON is parsed and put in req.body. For raw binary data, you really don't want this because they take time and memory to parse, and usually you never care about keeping these in memory.
So to efficiently deal with uploads, you should keep them as streams. req.pipe() is one function to deal with streams (but there's many others).

So figure out what you want to do with the file (write to filesystem, write to s3? re-upload somewhere else?) all those destinations for your file will accept streams. This is the correct and most efficient way to deal with this.
